# New Instance gets Keyword parameter from previous instance in Python

Tags: python, class, instance, keyword-argument

I have a question regarding new instances in Python.
The following code as a minimal example

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *p, **k):
        inst = object.__new__(cls)
        return inst

    def __init__(self, params=[]):
        self.params = params

    def add_param(self, p):
        self.params.append(p)


a = A()
print a.params
a.add_param(1)
a.add_param(2)
print a.params


b = A()
print b.params
```

With output

```
[]
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
```

From my basic understanding I would have suspected, that `b` would also have an empty parameter list. However, `b` is created with the parameters added to `a`.

So, my question is: Why is that and how can I get to instantiate b without any parameters (apart from explicitly providing params=[] as an argument).

Comment: You're using a mutable default argument.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for pointing out how this is called.